# confused in "type defines behaviour,not size"

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and just started reading my java textbook...
When I was going through data types there is a line which says that

> The width of an integer type should not be thought of as the amount of storage it consumes, but rather as the behaviour it defines for variables and expressions of that type.

This line created confusion that how width can be defined as behaviour and what type of "behaviour"are they taking about...
So I want to know the exact meaning of the above line.thanks in advance

Comment: "*So an int always occupies 32 bits (= 4 bytes). I think that may mean that on 64-bit PCs the JVM may leave half a word vacant when storing an int. I believe that used to happen for byte short and char, before Java1.4, but I might be mistaken. But whatever the amount of storage used, we programmers ignore that. The idea behind using a high-level language is that we can forget that sort of thing. We simply remember that an int behaves as having a "width" of 32 bits, and that's that.*"

Source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/441676/java/java/width-integer-type-thought-amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Riley Carney** pointed out in the comments above the **size is not about the physical storage space(JVM will taken care of that)**. 
That is, for the programmer it should not be a concern on how it will behave in different machines. Rather  to a programmer ,

**int data type is to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 232-1.**

Comment: Last sentence is plain wrong for Java.  `int` data type does *not* represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, but a [32-bit signed two's complement integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1.